# What is multiobjective clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I don't understand what is the multiobjective clustering is it using multiple variables for clustering or what?
I know that stack overflow might not be the best for this kind of questions, but 
I've asked it on other website and I did not got a response.

Comment: You should probably just Google it

Comment: I've googled it. All the results was papers that used multiobjective clustering but i didn't found any clear definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiobjective optimization in general means that you have multiple criterions which you are interested in, which cannot be simply converted to something comparable. For example consider problem when you try to have very fast model and very accurate one. Time is measured in s, accuracy in %. How do you compare (1s, 90%) and (10days, 92%)? Which one is better? In general there is no answer. Thus what people usually do - they look for pareto front, so you test K models and selec M <= K of them such that, none of them is clearly "beaten" by any else. For example if we add (1s, 91%) to the previous example, Pareto front will be {(1s, 91%), (10days, 92%)} (as (1s, 90%) < (1s, 91%), and remaining ones are impossible to compare).

And now you can apply the same problem in clustering setting. Say for example that you want to build a model which is fast to classify new instances, minimizes avg. distance inside each cluster, and does not put into each cluster too many special instances labeled with X. Then again you will get models (clusterings) which are now characterized by 3, not comparable, measures, and in Multiobjective Clustering you try to deal with these problems (like for example finding Pareto front of such clusterings).